# LDAPMAP - Mapping SAP data to LDAP via RSLDAPSYNC_USER function

Tags: active-directory, ldap, abap, sap-basis, function-module

We are looking at syncing some of our LDAP (Active Directory) data with what is stored in SAP. SAP provides several function modules that allow you to write a custom program to handle mapping the data, but we are looking to use the provided solution that makes use of RSLDAPSYNC_USER.

The issue I'm having is understanding how the mapping of fields is performed in LDAPMAP.  In particular, when performing the Mapping Overview, where are the structures as shown below defined?

[image]

Also, we have a function module that is currently available for grabbing all of the fields we would like to send to LDAP, but can the screen shown below be used to call a custom function module to grab the data I require?  If so, then please give an example.

[image]

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you ask. As an answer to your second question:

You can give attributes that you want to get. The `LDAP_READ` function will return the results in entries parameter.

```
    CALL FUNCTION 'LDAP_READ'
      EXPORTING
        base         = base
*       scope        = 2
        filter       = filter
*       attributes   = attributes_ldap
        timeout      = s_timeout
        attributes   = t_attributes_ldap
      IMPORTING
        entries      = t_entries_ldap              "<< entries will come
      EXCEPTIONS
        no_authoriz  = 1
        conn_outdate = 2
        ldap_failure = 3
        not_alive    = 4
        other_error  = 5
        OTHERS       = 6.
```

Entries parameter looks like: 
[image]

Attributes parameter looks like:

[image: Attributes parameter looks like]